# How to install a web development package for MS SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, installation, web-platform-installer

I am looking to install a web development package which uses PHP and SQL Server. My OS is Windows XP Professional SP3. After downloading Windows Web Platform Installer, I am confronted with a list of about 100 Products to choose from. I would like to know which are the essentials for the task at hand, which is programming using raw PHP and T-SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can downloag xampp for xp-3 it is best

Comment: mysql will not help me.